# custom calculation field in adobe acrobat pro

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

when i put this in, i get the nothing:

```
event.value = ( this.getField("PLRegTotal").value * this.getField("RegPlumberLaborRate").value ) + ( this.getField("HRegTotal").value * this.getField("RegHelperLaborRate").value ) + ( this.getField("PlOTTotal").value * this.getField("OTPlumberLabor").value ) + ( this.getField("HOTTotal").value * this.getField("OTHelperLaborRate").value );
```

However if I just have this:

```
event.value = ( this.getField("PLRegTotal").value * this.getField("RegPlumberLaborRate").value ) + ( this.getField("HRegTotal").value * this.getField("RegHelperLaborRate").value );
```

it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `adobe` is a pretty broad tag to use here. adobe makes a lot of programs

Comment: Put an `app.alert` on every field and make sure they exist. Don't just check from the GUI, either, actually put out code like `app.alert(this.getField("PLRegTotal"));`. Since we don't have your PDF I can only guess but it looks like `PL` is a prefix. In one case you are using uppercase `L` and in another case you are using a lowercase one, is that correct? `PlOTTotal` and `PLRegTotal`

Comment: Yes PL is a prefix and one is upper case and one is lower.  I don't know what an app.alert is, as I am new to javascript. Can you please xplain?